# How to convert date in specific format in Freemarker template or javascript

Tags: javascript, date, freemarker

From json, i am getting the value as

```
"createdOn": "Jan 08 2015 20:40:56 GMT+0530 (IST)",
```

I am Accessing in FTL

```
<#list variables as variable>
  <div class="reply">
   ${variable.createdOn}
  </div>
</#list>
```

The result i am getting is

```
Jan 09 2015 12:36:18 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

My preferable format is
**`09-01-2015`**

I need to remove rest of the time GMT, IST and so on.

How to convert this in Freemarker template or javascript.

**Update**

I tried to pass below like this

```
${variable.createdOn?datetime?string("dd-MM-yyyy")}
```

but it is giving error as

```
Exception: java.text.ParseException - Unparseable date: "Jan 09 2015 12:36:18 GMT+0530 (IST)"
```

Any help is Appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all, what format is that at all? I mean, if you can influence someone to use a standard format instead (ISO, mostly) that will help everyone. Anyway, FreeMarker isn't a date parser library, but actually you can do something like this:

```
<#-- Settings you need -->
<#setting date_format="dd-MM-yyyy">
<#setting locale="en_US">

<#-- The string that comes from somewhere: -->
<#assign createdOn = 'Jan 08 2015 20:40:56 GMT+0530 (IST)'>

<#--
  1. Tell FreeMarker to convert string to real date-time value
  2. Convert date-time value to date-only value
  3. Let FreeMarker format it according the date_format setting
-->
${createdOn?datetime("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z")?date}
```

Comment: thank you.. this is working `<#setting date_format="dd-MM-yyyy">
<#setting locale="en_US">
<#assign createdOn = variable.createdOn>
${createdOn?datetime("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z")?date} `

Answer (score 14):

This will format Your date:

```
"${variable.createdOn?datetime?string('dd-MM-yyyy')}"
```

Here is link to documentation: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html

Comment: @ Beri , i have tried this.it is giving `Exception: java.text.ParseException - Unparseable date: "Jan 09 2015 12:36:18 GMT+0530 (IST)"`

Comment: @rakesh I believe you should replace the double quotes with single ones.

Answer (score 2):

```
function convertDate( date ){
    dateSplit = date.toString().split( ' ' );
    dateSplit[1] = date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() : date.getMonth() + 1;
    return dateSplit[2] + '-' + dateSplit[1] +  '-' + dateSplit[3];
}

convertDate(new Date());
```

This should do the job. You can tweak it additionally

Comment: @Bowdzone, thank you for the edit suggestion, it was my first reply, and I didn't notice it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom function and use `getDate`, `getMonth` and `getFullYear` methods to format your date.

*Note that you must parse your string date format into Date object.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display todays day of the month in dd-MM-yyyy format.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date("Jan 08 2015 20:40:56 GMT+0530 (IST)"); //parsing your string date format into Date object.

var z = d.getDate() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getFullYear();
   
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you arman, but it is not solving my question. the created date may vary like yesterday, today or one month back. i mean to say i need to read it from the json. sorry if i am not clear.

Comment: I edited my code. You must parse your string format from JSON into Date object

Comment: You want also to print options 'yesterday', 'month back' and so on - depending on your date?

Answer (score 0):

I went this way. I created an object - formatter and pass it into template model. And I call formatter.format(date) in the template.

*template.ftl*

```
<div class="historyOrderItem">
    <div>
    <div>Created <#if order.created??>${formatter.format(order.created)}</#if></div>
    <div>Amount ${order.amount!}</div>
    <div>Currency ${order.currency!}</div>
</div>
```

*OrderPresenter.java*

```
@Component
public class OrderPresenter {

    private static final String FORMATTER_PARAM = "formatter";
    private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    private Configuration configuration = prepareConfiguration();

    public String toHtmlPresentation(ClientDetails clientDetails) {
        try {
            Template template = configuration.getTemplate(CLIENT_DATA_TEMPLATE);
            Writer out = new StringWriter();
            template.process(toMap(clientDetails), out);
            return out.toString();
        } catch (IOException | TemplateException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private Configuration prepareConfiguration() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23);
        configuration.setDefaultEncoding(ENCODING);
        configuration.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
        configuration.setLogTemplateExceptions(NOT_TO_LOG_EXCEPTIONS);
        configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(OrderPresenter.class, TEMPLATES_FOLDER);
        return configuration;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> toMap(ClientDetails clientDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> res = new HashMap<>();
        res.put(CLIENT_DETAILS_PARAM, clientDetails);
        res.put(FORMATTER_PARAM, FORMATTER);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*template.ftl*

```
<#list listaCategoria as c>
   <tr>
      <td> ${c.dataCadastro?datetime("yyyy-MM-dd")?string("dd/MM/yyyy")}</td>
   </tr>
</#list>
```

*RelatorioService.java*

```
LocalDate dataCadastro = LocalDate.of(1995, 12, 7);
```

Result:

```
07/12/1995
```