# How to convert date to string in freemarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

i did this way..

```
<#assign createdOn='${receipt.arPaymDate}'>
${createdOn?datetime("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z")?date}
```

But i am getting below execption

> Can't convert the date-like value to string because it isn't known if
>   it's a date (no time part), time or date-time value. The blamed
>   expression: ==> receipt.arPaymDate [in template
>   "WEB-INF/ftl/receiptPdf.ftl" at line 22, column 47]

thanks in advened

Comment: It's hardly the error message of the example shown though, as there you are using `?date`, so FreeMarker will known that it's a date-only value.

Comment: `${createdOn?datetime(...)}` expects `createdOn` to be a `Date`. However, you have initialized it as `createdOn = '${...}'`, which makes it a `String` (value wrapped in quotes). Try `<#assign createdOn = receipt.arPaymDate />`.

Answer (score 1):

You may need first init the date format

```
<#setting date_format="dd-MM-yyyy">

<#assign createdOn='${receipt.arPaymDate}'> 
${createdOn?datetime("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z")?date}
```

Also see [How to convert date in specific format in Freemarker template or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857058/how-to-convert-date-in-specific-format-in-freemarker-template-or-javascript)

Comment: @ wodong thank you , i did little bit modification and its wroking for me thank you

Comment: This answer has problems: unnecessary usage of `'${...}'` in assignment, and unnecessary usage of both `?datetime` and `?date`. But see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what's the type of `receipt.arPaymDate` is.

In any case, you shouldn't write `<#assign createdOn='${receipt.arPaymDate}'>`, but `<#assign createdOn=receipt.arPaymDate>`, as the former converts `receipt.arPaymDate` to a string (as you insert into an empty string there), even if it was already a `java.util.Date`. If it was a `String`, then it does nothing, so it's needless verbosity.

If `receipt.arPaymDate` is a `java.util.Date`, and you do the assignment without the `'${...}'`, you don't need the `?datetime(...)` part, only the `?date` part: `${createdOn?date}`. (Even the `?date` can be omitted if `receipt.arPaymDate` is a `java.sql.Date`, as that's known to store the date part only, not time.)

If  `receipt.arPaymDate` is a string, so you must parse it to date, you can just write `${createdOn?date("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z")}`. It's not a problem that the pattern has time part, `?date` will still mark the result as a date-only value.

Also, just in case it wasn't clear, the assignment in this example is unnecessary. One can just write `${receipt.arPaymDate?date}`.